# Can not run qq in my CentOS

Tags: centos

When I execute the qq in CentOS, I get the bellow error:

> /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not run the i386 program (qq) in the 64bit system.

You should install the `glibc.i686`, then try do that:

```
sudo yum install glibc.i686
```

Comment: The directory is the qq location, it shows qq is i386 version